# Confusing behavior of C program, printf

Tags: c, printf

How come printf("prompt:") will not print immediately? I have tried fflush(stdout) and placing a \n but neither of those worked. It only prints when "See you" prints:

```
int main() {
    char line[1025];
    char command[80], argument[80];
    char argv[3][80];
    int i, pid;
    *(argv[2]) = '\0';

    while((fgets(line, 1024, stdin))) {
      printf("prompt:");

      line[1024] = '\0';
      sscanf(line, " %s %s ", command, argument);

       if(strcmp(command, "exit") == 0 || strcmp(command, "hastalavista") == 
          0) {
          printf("See you\n");
          exit(0);
       } 
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard I/O (i.e. functions from `<stdio.h>`) is *buffered* (and often line-buffered, notably for `stdout`).

You need to flush it (e.g. by calling `fflush(stdout);`)

BTW, you are calling `fgets` *before* `printf("prompt:");`. It looks wrong. I suggest to `printf("prompt:"); fflush(stdout);` *before* calling `fgets`.

Of course, you should compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

At last, on POSIX systems you could use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). On Linux systems you could even use [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html).

With [sscanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) you'll better test its return item count (and you might want to use `%n`).

You probably should read more about terminals (on POSIX systems at least), e.g. the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page, and about [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline). See also [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) & i[satty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html).

Answer (score 3):

`while((fgets(line, 1024, stdin)))` :- This means that read from `stdin` and put content in `line`. `fgets` will not return until it receives EOF or New Line character. That means, Your code will *wait* until you press "Enter" key.

If you don't press it, it will not go ahead and print "Prompt". That's why delayed!

And, Whatever you type before pressing enter will be stored in `line` (Max 1024 bytes)

Comment: I believe that `fgets` will wait for an entire line and store at most the first 1024 bytes of it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 2nd parameter in `fgets` specify "maximum number of characters to be read". It will stop reading if 1024 bytes are received.

Comment: It will also stop reading if a newline is encountered.  It also won't return anything until the data is sent to the program by hitting the return key, whether that's with more or less than 1024 characters entered.  On some systems, the terminal driver won't accept as many as 1024 characters in a single line; the limit is smaller, like 256 bytes or so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ohh! Okay!

Comment: @Swanand Detail: It will stop reading if 1023 bytes are received, one less than the size parameter.  After reading text, `fgets()` appends a null character. The null character is not part of what was read.

Comment: ...and the OP should note there was no need to allocate a "spare" byte with `char line[1025];`